# recaptcha's invalid-request-cookie

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha

I use reCaptcha and installed its [php libraries](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/detail?name=recaptcha-php-1.11.zip&can=2&q=label%3aphplib-Latest) . Anytime I send request to the server using the function 'recaptcha_check_answer' I get in response the error 'invalid-request-cookie'.

I've checked hundred of times if my challenge is ok, and also if I don't use SSL by mistake. So, anyone knows what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am almost facing the same issue see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966516/recaptcha-invalid-request-cookie-on-server, if you find a solution do post it